# I've created an AJAX call to send data to a stored procedure. Why isn't it working?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I will post my code and I'm curious if anyone can see what I am doing wrong here.  I've tested the Stored Procedure and that works fine so the break must be somewhere in the Controller or Model.  See code below:

VIEW:

```js
function saveCalc() {
    var TotCost = $("#totCost").val();
    var GPM = $("#CalcAmt").val();
    var SP = parseFloat(TotCost / (1 - GPM));
    var ID = parseInt($("#ID").val());
    
    debugger;
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Items/ItemsReport_Update2',
        type: "Get",
        data: { ID: ID, SP: SP },
        success: function () {
            CalcDialog.close();
            CalcDestroy();

            $('#ItemsReportgrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
            $('#ItemsReportgrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```cs
public void ItemsReport_Update2(int ID, double SP)
{
    ItemsModel oItemsModel = new ItemsModel();
    oItemsModel.UpdateItemsReport2(ID, SP);
}
```

MODEL:

```cs
public void UpdateItemsReport2(int ID, double SP)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateInvItem2", con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SP", SP);

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I've run the script with a debugger and it is passing the data correctly.

Comment: Nevermind...I figured it out.  I forgot the / before the Items URL so it was looking in the controller for a method called Items instead of a method called ItemsReport_Update2

Answer (score 0):

```
 url: '/Items/ItemsReport_Update2',
```

You **missed '/'** in ajax URL

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that grid is not populating with the result data.

Please change your controller like this if you are loading a kendo grid data:

```cs
public void ItemsReport_Update2([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,
                                int ID, double SP)
{
    // Create a list with your model type
    List<> lst = new List<>();
    ItemsModel oItemsModel = new ItemsModel();
    oItemsModel.UpdateItemsReport2(ID, SP);

    DataSourceResult result = lst.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then you need to change the javascript like this:

```js
function saveCalc() {
    var TotCost = $("#totCost").val();
    var GPM = $("#CalcAmt").val();
    var SP = parseFloat(TotCost / (1 - GPM));
    var ID = parseInt($("#ID").val());

    var grid = $("#ItemsReportgrid").data('kendoGrid');

    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Items/ItemsReport_Update2',
        type: "Get",
        data: { ID: ID, SP: SP },
        success: function (result) {
            grid.dataSource.data(result.Data);

            CalcDialog.close();
            CalcDestroy();
        }
    });
}
```